# Special characters display as garbage in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, special-characters

I recently started using Chrome for web development (previously I used FireFox) and I've run into an issue.

If I submit the special character `Ω` via POST and then in PHP do `die($_POST['thatvar']);`, then FireFox shows the `Ω` symbol on the page (and in FireBug), but Chrome shows `Î©` on the page (though it shows `Ω` in the dev. tools).

Why is this happening?

Comment: what charset is the page set to. you probably set ff to utf8 by defult, but not chrome. but you should be setting it within the page html\headers regardless

Comment: @Dagon - is this a browser setting that you are talking about?

Comment: both, you set it in the page, but if you don't the browser will use its default

Comment: You probably need `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your `<head>`. (Or whatever encoding you're using on the page. As Dagon said, it's probably UTF-8 because that is the default in FF, where the character is displaying correctly).

Comment: ^ +1. browser encoding defaults unless specified in your `<head>`. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use charset in the head

by adding

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
```

in your head

like :

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;  charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: Since I was echoing stuff out to the page, Dagon's comment actually solved my problem, but this probably would have worked, too.